# What does ! (exclamatory) mark inside curly braces ({}) when using variable in unix

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Let ***var*** be a variable and it assigned a value ***/home/user*** as below

```
var=/home/user
```

when using this variable, i have seen it using both of the below format,

```
1) cd ${var}
2) cd ${!var}
```

what is the difference? for me second option is not working , if i ***echo*** second option returns empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it's indirect expansion<sup>(a)</sup>, the `var` variable is expanded to create another variable name and then *that* is expanded again to get your eventual result:

```
pax$ abc=def
pax$ def=ghi
pax$ echo ${abc}   # abc -> def,        one level.
def
pax$ echo ${!abc}  # abc -> def -> ghi, two levels.
ghi
```

From the `bash` man page:

> If  the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), it introduces a level of variable indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself. This is known as indirect expansion.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It can have other more complex effects in other situations, such as when you use `${!prefix*}` or `${!name[@]}` but your case is the simpler one.

Comment: is there a way to expand multiple times like `abc -> def -> ghi -> jkl` ?